# Simulate a button on the keyboard being pressed, add the value of that keypress to text input

Tags: javascript, html

My objective is to be able to run a function that simulates a key being pressed on the keyboard, and then the value of that key being inserted into an input field. My reasoning for this is that I am using a js framework that automatically filters data based off of the input but it only filters the data when the input is typed in. Using `document.getElementById('search_box').value` will obviously populate the input with text. But doing this doesn't trigger the data to be filtered because the input text technically isn't typed in. So I was wondering if it was possible to run a function that would basically simulate keys being pressed and then inserting the value of those keys into an input field.

```
function populateField() {
    document.getElementById('search_box').value = "mr"; //this needs to be changed to insert the value via keyboard
    document.getElementById('search_box').focus();
}
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

Comment: which framework are you using? the framework SHOULD have an API that allows you to trigger this without keyboard events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to filter.js's main repo's [Issues #154](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/issues/154): *Can I trigger a filter programatically with jquery like $("#filterid").val("bla").change() ?*

`$("#filterid").trigger('change')` will work. It also depend upon events: change, click etc

i.e
`$('#searchbox').val("father").trigger('keyup')`

In the [example page](http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/index.html) , I used `$('#searchbox').val("father").trigger('keyup')` to add "father" to search and trigger a filter effect.

Comment: @AaronHorne the following works for the example page:
http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/index.html

`$('#searchbox').val("father").trigger('keyup')`

Comment: yes that definitely works, and makes sense too. thanks for the help

Comment: @AaronHorne you are welcome. please mark this as the correct answer. thanks.